# Using ElementTree to extract <content:encoded>

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm currently trying to figure out how to extract the content between <content:encoded> and </content:encoded> using ElementTree in Python. Attached below is the Python code I'm currently using to solve this. I've currently been unable to extract the content. I want to extract "I love playing basketball and eating food". Can anyone help me to see what's wrong with my code?

```
xml = '''<item>
        <title>Defensive Moves</title>
        <link>www.timmy256.wordpress.com</link>
        <pubDate></pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[jross]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"> www.timmy256.wordpress.com </guid>   
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[I love playing basketball and eating food.]]></content:encoded>
        </item>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
data = root.iter("content:encoded").text
```

Comment: [`tree = ET.fromsring(xml)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) ??

Comment: Even after using `.fromstring` there is a namespace issue - do you have to use etree? do you care about the namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another mothod.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
xml = '''<item>
        <title>Defensive Moves</title>
        <link>www.timmy256.wordpress.com</link>
        <pubDate></pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[jross]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"> www.timmy256.wordpress.com </guid>   
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[I love playing basketball and eating food.]]></content:encoded>
        </item>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
print(doc.select('item>content:encoded>html()')[9:-3])
```

Result:

```
I love playing basketball and eating food.
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples